# Problems getting Mocha tests to wait for db to be built

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, mocha.js

I have the following code which is designed to create a test db, upgrade it, seed it with data and then run a bunch of mocha tests:-

```
 await createDatabase().then(async () => {
        console.log("upgrading database");
        await dbUpgrade().then(async () => {
            console.log("seeding database");
            await seedTestDatabase().then(() => {
```

After "seedTestDatabase", I call all my test suites. When I run this code, I get the following in the console:-

Opening database ./db/test.sqlite
listening on port 4001
creating database
upgrading database
starting upgrade

0 passing (1ms)

finished upgrade
seeding database
seeding test database
starting tests

For some reason, Mocha decides in the middle of the db upgrade function that it can't find any tests! If I run the functions createDatabase, dbUpgrade then seedDatabase manually one by one, everything works. What's going on with Mocha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably, it can work with mochajs

```js
describe('test database is build', function(){ 

  this.timeout(60 * 1000); // mocha terminates tests after 3 seconds with timeout error

  it('creates database', function() {
    return createDatabase();
  });
  it('updates database', function() {
    return dbUpgrade();
  });
  it('seeds database', function() {
    return seedTestDatabase();
  });
});
```

if we assume each function depicted in question returns promise, we can call all them as test suit items in promise style approach sequently